# Unwanted Print Setup

Tags: vba, excel, printing, installation

So I'm experiencing some weird behavior while trying to open a new workbook (checkwb). When the new workbook opens it opens a "Print Setup" dialog box for every single page in the workbook. Furthermore, after clicking "OK" ~200 times the code runs fine, but if I close checkwb and try to run the code again it is unable to open checkwb until I close Excel entirely and reopen, at which point the print dialogs reappear. Here's my (incomplete) code:

```
Sub Check()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim homewb As Workbook
Dim checkwb As Workbook

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim namestr As String

Dim checkarray() As Double

Set homewb = Workbooks("BranchTable Calc B31.3.xlsm")
Set checkwb = Workbooks.Open("Z:\Agrium\Redwater\E130040CP ~ Pipe Spec  
Update\M-Mech\20-Eng\Calcs\Final WT Calcs All Specs\New Bechtel Agrium  
comments.xlsm")

For Each ws In homewb.Sheets
    If ws.Name = "Cover" Or ws.Name = "Pipe Dims" Then
    Else:
        namestr = ws.Name & " Weld"
        checkarray() = GetCheckValues(checkwb, namestr)
    End If
Next

checkwb.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I've read weird errors like this can occur from corrupted files but the code shouldn't be able to open the file at all if it was corrupt by my understanding.

Comment: There are a few issues I found online with similar behavior, since the files you're attempting to work with are .xlsm the obvious would be to make sure there are no macros within those files causing the issue.

Also excel apparently needs a connected printer to be reachable when a file was saved in "Page Break Preview" mode. If there is a network printer listed as the default and it becomes unreachable, you'll see this issue. That's really all I could find about it though.

Comment: Just went to the book I was opening, set all page views to "Normal " mode and ran the code again. Worked perfectly, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the page view for all sheets in the target workbook to "Normal" mode fixed this problem. Thanks to Ricardo Rodrigues for the tip!